# Remove a key from a hash table efficiently

Tags: c++, performance, hash-map

I am trying to remove a key from a hash table, which is built using linear probing. Removing a key works fine but I know I need to rehash a portion of the table after the removal but my method down below is not quite efficient. It basically rehashes the whole table that is unnecessary. Is there anyway that I could improve the performance while rehashing.

```
bool remove(int x, int H[], int m)
{
    int hashVal = hash(x, m);
    for (int i = 0; H[(hashVal + i) % m] != EMPTY; i++)
    {
        if (H[(hashVal + i) % m] == x)
        {
            H[(hashVal + i) % m] = EMPTY;

           //Rehash the table
           //I think the problem is here. This for loop condition can be better
            for (int k = 1; H[(hashVal + i + k) % m] != EMPTY ; k++)
            {
                int keyShiftUp = H[(hashVal + i + k) % m];

                H[(hashVal + i + k) % m] = EMPTY;

                insertLP(keyShiftUp, H, m);

                cout << "keyShiftUp: " << keyShiftUp << ends;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Answer (score 3):

**C++, not C**

First things first, I note that `remove` is a free function. But that's not how we would do something like this in C++. We would prefer to have a type `HashTable` in which we'd write:

```
class HashTable {
public:
   ...
   bool remove(int key);
   ...

private:
   int hash(int );

   std::vector<int> table; // vector is better than int*
                           // table is a better name than H
};
```

Your naming also could use some work - what is `x` and what is `m`? I'm guessing `m` is the capacity and `x` is the key that we're erasing, but where are the values? We just have `int H[]`, so is this more like a hash set than a hash table? It's unclear.

**Looping and separation of concerns**

The hash function should just do the hashing (and thus shouldn't take in the capacity). The loop itself should loop over slots, not indices - this will localize your modulo operation so it doesn't creep in everywhere:

```
int next(int i) {
    return (i+1) % table.size();
}

bool remove(int key) {
    int i = hash(key) % table.size(); 
    if (table[i] == EMPTY) {          // break early
        return false;
    }

    for (; table[i] != EMPTY; i = next(i)) {
        if (table[i] == key) {
            table[i] = EMPTY;

            for (int k = next(i); table[k] != EMPTY; k = next(k)) {
               ...
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Once you reorient looping over additive indices to looping over actual indices, the inner body becomes more straightforward too:

```
int old_key = table[k];
table[k] = EMPTY;
insert(old_key);
```

**Find the slot**

Your `i` loop is all about finding the slot where the `key` is at. The body of that loop isn't really a loop, it's a `find`-type algorithm. So let's rewrite it like one:

```
bool remove(int key) {
    int i = hash(key) % table.size(); 
    for (; table[i] != key; i = next(i)) {
        if (table[i] == EMPTY) {          // break early
            return false;
        }
    }

    // now, table[i] == key
    table[i] = EMPTY;
    for (int k = next(i); table[k] != EMPTY; k = next(k)) {
        int old_key = table[k];
        table[k] = EMPTY;
        insert(old_key);
    }

    return true;
}
```

**`EMPTY`**

In addition to not really being a hash *table*, you're seemingly limiting the possible valid keys to exclude something like `0` or `-1` or whatever the value of `EMPTY` is. May be worth separating the key from the empty concept.